# Powershell is it possible to store csv headers and value in hashtable

Tags: powershell, csv

Is it possible to store entire CSV file data in hashtable as headers as keys and respective values as value pair?

I wanted this use in pushing correct data in SQL table.

Sample csv file:

```
id,fname,lname,shift,day,night
1,ert,sdf,08/21/2017 Day,2,-
2,wer,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,1
3,rty,adsf,08/21/2017 Day,1,-
4,yui,adsf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
5,qwe,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
6,ret,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
7,chh,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
8,sdf,cxvv,08/21/2017 Day,1,-
```

I wanted to access in values so I can loop over keys, something like:

```
id => 1
fname => ert
lname => sdf
shift => 08/21/2017 Day
day => 2
night => -
id => 2
fname => wer
lname => asdf
shift => 08/21/2017 Day
day => -
night => 1
...
So on
```

Comment: [`Import-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-5.1). Please consider editing your question. It's hard to understand.

Comment: How would you distinguish the rows if they're all keyed by column header?

Comment: Each row is an indexed element in the returned object, as already shown by Nahuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In adition to Nahuel's answer, looping through the item's keys looks as follows:

```
$csvData = Import-CSV data.csv

foreach ($element in $csvData) {
    Write-Host "Element:"
    $element.Keys | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "`t$($_) => $($element[$_])"}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `Import-Csv` Cmdlet

```
>  $csvData=Import-Csv example.csv

>  $csvData[0]

id    : 1
fname : ert
lname : sdf
shift : 08/21/2017 Day
day   : 2
night : -

>  $csvData[0].shift

08/21/2017 Day

>  $csvData.length

8
```

so valid keys are 0..7

EDIT : to loop over keys

```
$keys = $csvData[0].psobject.properties | % { ,@( $_.name ) }

$csvData[0].($keys[0])
```

or

```
$keys | %{ echo "$_ => $($csvData[0].$_)" }
```

and

```
0..7 |%{ $i=$_; $keys |%{ echo "$i,$_ => $($csvData[$i].$_)" } }
```

Comment: In addition to your answer, as OP wants to loop through keys: `$csvData.Keys | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "`$_ => $($csvData[$_])"}` edit:Sure, it has to be in it's own iteration.